Foundry Emit Event on Return Value
I have a create account function that will return the address and I want to test the event logging but getting an error log != expected log
My function
 function createAccount(address accountContract, uint256 chainId, address nftContract, uint256 nftId, uint256 salt)
        external
        returns (address)
    {
        bytes memory code = _creationCode(accountContract, chainId, nftContract, nftId, salt);
        address _account = Create2.computeAddress(bytes32(salt), keccak256(code));

        if (_account.code.length != 0) return _account;

        _account = Create2.deploy(0, bytes32(salt), code);

        emit AccountCreated(_account, accountContract, chainId, nftContract, nftId, salt);

        return _account;
    }


My test
 event AccountCreated(
        address indexed account,
        address indexed implementation,
        uint256 chainId,
        address tokenContract,
        uint256 tokenId,
        uint256 salt
    );

 function test_EmitEvent_AccountCreated() public {
        vm.expectEmit(true, true, false, false);
        emit AccountCreated(registryAddress, address(account), chainId, address(nftCollection), 1, 0);

        address registryAddress = registry.createAccount(address(account), chainId, address(nftCollection), 1, 0);
    }

from what I understand is that the registryAddress will return as zero address and will only commit after createAccount is executed, so how do I make the event log successful?

You can divide your test into two separate tests, and revert in your createAccount() function if _account == address(0), and then test for that expectRevert in one test and expectEmit in the other (i.e., that you've already created as test_EmitEvent_AccountCreated).
